# Не создается java поток на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, linux

Когда тестирую свою программу на компьютере поток создается без проблем и программа работает корректно, но если я запускаю тот же .jar файл на сервере (ubuntu 16.04), программа запускается и работает, но только в 1 потоке. Как быть?
https://pp.userapi.com/c831109/v831109019/a0125/b0FvRpKFlPc.jpg

Comment: приложите ваш код к телу вопроса, нажав на править. и добавьте команду как вы запускаете

Comment: Нет, скриншот не катит. Давай-ка пополнее картину выставляй и текстом, текстом!

Answer (score 1):

Из-за того что одноядерный процессор на сервере, программа не работала

Comment: Странная программа.

Comment: количество потоков в программе не обязано совпадать с количество CPU ядер.

Comment: сомневаюсь, что в количестве ядер была проблемма